# Correct way to trigger updates in a component when a service changes it's state in Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

What is the recommended way to trigger updates in a component when a service changes it's state? I.e. I have a boolean (`isConnected`) in a service and I want a components view to update with the value of this boolean. I feel that this should be a pretty straightforward thing to achieve.
As of now I have a rxjs Subject (`connectionStatusChange`) in the service. I subscribe to this Subject from the component.

```
this.theService.connectionStatusChange.subscribe(connected => {
  this.connected = connected;
  this.cd.detectChanges();
  console.log('subscription triggered in ble component: ' + connected);
});
```

For some reason I **have** to use `cd.detectChanges()` to make this work. Isn't there a more correct way?
Grateful for any suggestions!

Comment: so you are using observable and i think its a good way.

Comment: Are you able to create a StackBlitz that reproduces the issue? It should work without the `.detectChanges()`...

Comment: Eventually I managed to make it work. Both without using an observable or calling `.detectChanges()`.
What I'm doing now is trigger `appRef.tick()` back in the service when I change the service boolean. When i do this I can use the injected service directly in my templates and it updates correctly. My understanding is that the code that assigns the boolean for some reason runs outside the zone which will require the manual `.tick()`. But I still don't understand why using an observable won't "force" it back into the zone?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call detectChanges, Observables is mainly used to handle async operation which by default triggers change detection.

Might be, you are using Ionic/Native Function which will internally trigger the Cordova Native Code, i.e Code execution happen outside of Angular. We need to inform Angular to update the DOM.

**Possible Solution:**

- ngZone.run(()=>{}) => which will trigger change detection to whole application
- changeDetectorRef.detectChanges() => which will trigger child components and sibbling
- setTimeout(()=>{}) => which will trigger change detection to whole application

Answer (score 0):

Have faced the same issue before.
The problem occurs when a data model is modified, but Angular doesn't detect the modification on its own. Therefore, the change detection has to be programatically triggered.
If you have something like this happening, try destroying the data model and creating it again. Such as setting the variable to null or [] and then assigning it data.